# How to Unit Test ajax jquery function inside document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unit-testing

I have a script that makes $.ajax request for a json api. So what I want to do is to build unit test so I can test the result from the ajax request. For example if I get json object back. I know result should include "items" and "result" which is an array. The things is I dont know how to initialize the $.ajax function which is inside a

```
$("#button").click(function() { });
```

Here's the skeleton of my javascript index.js file. The file is not complete. as it is longer. I just included the relevant parts. But it works. Here's the app live online http://pctechtips.org/apps/books/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var item, tile, author, publisher, bookLink, bookImg;
  var outputList = document.getElementById("list-output");
  var bookUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
  var searchData;
$("#search").click(function() {
    outputList.innerHTML = ""; //empty html output
     searchData = $("#search-box").val();
     //handling empty search input field
     if(searchData === "" || searchData === null) {
       displayError();
     }
    else {
       // console.log(searchData);
       // $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+searchData, getBookData()});
       $.ajax({
          url: bookUrl + searchData,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            if (response.totalItems === 0) {
              alert("no result!.. try again")
            }
            else {
              $("#title").animate({'margin-top': '5px'}, 1000); //search box animation
              $(".book-list").css("visibility", "visible");
              displayResults(response);
            }
          },
          error: function () {
            alert("Something went wrong.. <br>"+"Try again!");
          }
        });
      }
      $("#search-box").val(""); //clearn search box
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test you need first to prepare a HTML fixture which will contain all the required elements like `#search`. After preparing it, you can load your script via `$.getScript()` - it will attach click event listener to `#search`. Finally, you have to spy on `$.ajax` and trigger the click manually via `$('#search').trigger('click')`